# image doesn't change size or doesn't align

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, stylesheet

hey i'm trying to get an image in a certain size on a content page but for some reason no mather what i do i doesn't change size or alignment eventhough trying to put it into a div container or changing style on the stylesheet...

this is a few things i tried on the webpage itseft

```
<div align="center" class="hotstonefoto"><img src="../images/hotstone.png" width="485" height="273" alt="" /> <img src="../images/hotstone.png"/></div>
```

and this is what i tried on the stylesheet:

```
.hotstonefoto{
   width: 100%;
   src:url(../../images/hotstone.png)
}
```

but nothing seems to work...

one thing that might be causing this (i have no idea as i'm not that well known with using it or what can be the effect of using it) is that the content pages load inside a div with a jquery command

thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `src:url(../../images/hotstone.png)`, Is not valid CSS. This should be `background-image:url(../../images/hotstone.png);`. But you would not put a background image on an image. So I am not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: was jus ttrying to try all kinds of things to figure out a way to get the image to get the size it needs to be or at least center...

Comment: You can't change the image source with CSS.

Comment: You might want to try something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/xyff6/1/

Comment: Are you trying to center the image in a container? Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xyff6/2/

Comment: or maybe he is trying something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xyff6/3/ so there the img has a width=100% so it gets the width from the parent div and changes if the div changes the div which you can change with media queries..

Comment: it needed to be something like the one from caramba, i'll try that later thanks a lot, i'll keep you guys posted on this :)

Comment: still no luck... you can see what i mean on the webpage if you want...

http://www.massagepraktijkanne.nl/test

if you go to tarieven in the menu and then hotstone you should see a explenation of what hotstone is and a picture of a hotstone massage that should get centered and bigger then it is now... the image is now a size of 485x273 but for some reason even with the code from caramba it just doesn't want to make it bigger or centered...

Comment: So 485x273 is the size you want? If so then just remove `width:110px` from `#welcome img` in your css.

Comment: thanks a lot kris that was indeed the problem with the size! the only problem i now still have is that it won't center although it does center in my editor :/